# A good algorithm for numerical computation of an integral of a polynomial times a function in $C^{\infty}$ over a compact set

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

Let $\Omega_{a,b} = [a,b]$ be a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$, $p_n$ a polynomial of degree $n$ and $f \in C^{\infty}(\Omega)$. I'm aware of the general numerical techniques that allow to compute numerically the integral of a function. However I was wondering whether for the specific case of

$$
\langle p_n,f\rangle  =\int_{\Omega_{a,b}} p_n(x) f(x) dx
$$

there's maybe a better computational technique. If $f$ is such that $f(x)=g^{(n)}(x)$, I guess an approach could be
$$ \begin{align*}
\langle p_n,f\rangle &= \langle p_n,g^{(n)} \rangle \\
&= \int_{\Omega_{a,b}} p_n(x)g^{(n)}(x)dx \\
&= \left. p_n(x)g^{(n-1)}(x) \right|_{\partial \Omega}-\int_{\Omega_{a,b}}p_{n}^{(1)}(x)g^{(n-1)}(x)dx \\
&= \left. p_n(x)g^{(n-1)}(x) \right|_{\partial \Omega_{a,b}}-\langle p^{(1)}_n,g^{(n-1)}\rangle  \\
\implies \\
\langle p_n,g^{(n)}\rangle  &= \left. p_n(x)g^{(n-1)}(x) \right|_{\partial \Omega_{a,b}}-\langle p^{(1)}_n,g^{(n-1)}\rangle 
\end{align*} $$

So I have the closed form

$$
\langle p_n,g^{(n)}\rangle  = \left. \sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{k}p_{n}^{(k)}(x)g^{(n-k)}(x) \right|_{\partial\Omega_{a,b}}
$$

But this would imply I need to know $g^{(0)},g^{(1)},\ldots g^{(n)}$ in $\partial\Omega_{a,b} = \left\{a,b\right\}$

Comment: I've reformatted the particularly long "equation" chain and implication to go over several lines.  Please check that I didn't inadvertently change your meaning or introduce errors.

Comment: @hardmath, Sounds ok thank you.

Comment: We could use the following fact about Schwartz functions: if $f\in\mathcal S(\mathbb R)$ then $\int f^{(m)}(x) x^k dx = 0$ if $k<m$ and $(-1)^m m!\int f(x) dx$ if $k=m$. You can show this by the exact chain of reasoning you used in your question. Then we would need to show one can approximate any function in $\mathcal C^\infty(\Omega)$ arbitrarily well by Schwartz-functions to transfer the result.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the technique you're proposing. How would I approximate my function $f$ using the Schwartz functions? Wouldn't I need to project my function in that space, which would probably involve the use of other integrals, is that right?

Comment: I just need that value extremely accurate values, given that each quadrature scheme has it's degree of accuracy I'm not sure which one I actually want. Ideally I'd like these to be representable using IEEE F64 format with half ulp error. I don't care that much about the speed.

Comment: (1) How are $p_n,f$ represented for your computation?  (2) Is there a single function $f$ involved or many?  If $f$ is a highly oscillatory function, your task is harder than if $f \gt 0$ everywhere on $[a,b]$.  Without more information I can't recommend a particular numerical integration routine.

Comment: You can assume $f$ is positive, defined in $[1,2]$ with image in $[1,2] $, you can also assume it is monotonically increasing or monotonically decreasing and strictly convex or strictly concave. I'm not assuming much about $p_n $, but for realistic case you can take $n \leq 3$.

Comment: Is there any better assumption on $p_n$ that would make my life easier?